# how to differentiate between 'int' and 'float' datatypes while using SLY in Python

Tags: python, lexer, sly

I am using **Sly** package in Python to make a **dummy Lexer**. here is the [documentation](https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which only states that tokens which are numbers can only be identified as NUMBER as we, the programmer defines it:

```
@_(r'\d+')
def NUMBER(self, t):
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t
```

Now I have tried adding a **separate function** for a FLOAT and INT type instead, but there are some complications:

I can't find anything to successfully read the input and identify it as a 'float' or an 'int' data type. Experimented with various things it 'yeilds', no luck.

I am now thinking of manipulating RegEx somehow but no luck in that either. I can't make it recognize a float by placing a dot between two digits like this:

```
@_(r'\d+.\d+') # this Expression
def FLOAT(self, t):
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t
```

Anyways, the output I want is something like this:

```
#input string
123 1.23
#output string (this is a simplified version of the original output)
TOKEN:123; ID:0; TYPE:int-datatype
TOKEN:1.23; ID:1; TYPE:float-datatype
```

> **NOTE:** I am very new to Sly

Comment: `([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?)([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?` Try this regex for floats, unsure if it works with the way Sly forwards numbers so let me know if it does and I can post it as an answer with a nexplanation.

Comment: This is the output:
    `>> 123
    Token(type='INT', value=123, lineno=1, index=0)
    >> 1.23
    Token(type='INT', value=1, lineno=1, index=0)`
and it also throws an **ValueError** exception:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.23'`

I guess we will have to write identification RegExs for int as well as float part of a complete float number. Then join them afterwards. At this point anything goes.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order in which you declare your INTEGER and FLOAT functions? The first to be declared will be tried first. So FLOAT then INTEGER means it will try to parse tokens as floats in preference to integers (rather than vice versa). Not sure if the is a conscious design decision or just some implementation detail though.

Comment: The documentation indicates that it is intentional. "Tokens are matched in the same order that patterns are listed in the Lexer class. "

Answer (score 1):

Just to quickly compile the details in comments into a visible answer:

- `([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?)([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?` will match a float value
- You would have to check for the float value first because Sly goes through lexing rules in order (also why, if you have a `==` literal and a `=` literal, you want to list them in that order rather than the reverse).